# Modifying resource contents of a running executable

Tags: c#, c++, windows, file, resources

All,

I store my application settings in a resource. When my program first loads, I read the specified resource using WinAPI. I then parse the retrieved byte data. This works flawlessly for me.

Now let's say that a user alters a setting in my application. He/she checks a checkbox control. I would like to save the updated setting to my resource. However, it seems that my call to UpdateResource will not work while my application is running. I can't modify my resource data even though it is the same size.

First, is it possible to modify a running image's resource data? Second, if that is not possible, what alternatives do I have for storing settings internally within my application?

NOTE: I must have the settings within my running executable. They cannot be on the harddrive or in the registry. Please don't even suggest that as an option.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? From where I'm sitting, asking this question indicates a serious flaw in your application's design. That deserves a full remedy, not a band-aid solution.

Comment: I was going to suggest the solution to your problem but you have explicitly stated that you do not want anyone to suggest a solution. Sorry that I can't help.

Comment: It will commonly not work even if your image isn't loaded in a process.  You can't get write access to a executable file when the user is appropriately restricted.  UAC being the common case.  Let's close this question, you are not interested in a real answer.

Comment: @Cody  Gary: I need this implemented this way. It must be within my application image.

Comment: @Hans Passant: This question is not for novice developers like you to even consider about answering. This is moreso for people who have run into the same problem as me and have some sort of solution. I need to modify an application in use. If I can use MoveFileEx to move a running image from one location to the next, why wouldn't this be possible if the size of the.section was equivalent?

Comment: I'll have to take that has a compliment, considering my age.  I'll work on that for a while.

Comment: @mrwoik you can't do this. You also don't want to do this but you unfortunately don't have the wit to let very experienced and respected developers help you. That is rather foolish.

Comment: What is with you folks telling others that things are "too advanced" for them, or that they're not good enough programmers? For one thing, rep alone at least indicates we're not not stumbling around in the dark. And perhaps more to the point, you don't know us or our skills, so please don't try to diminish them. There's a way to do just about anything; that doesn't mean it's a good idea. Those of us who have the experience to notice that right off the bat posted comments indicating such. We didn't post it as an answer, and good thing because you "give me teh codez" people would be downvoting.

Comment: Hans, David, Gray: Nobody asked your opinions about the solution. You were asked for help with the solution. Which you all failed miserably. There are people out here who work for money. You might have a nice boss with the "of course we give you enough time to refactor the entire project" attitude. Lucky you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is 100% possible to write self-modifying code. It's just not very easy to do.

When you launch your executable file, windows maps it in memory. This essentially locks the file and prevents edits while it is running. You can, obviously, unmap your program (by using an undocumented function in ntdll). When your file is unmapped, you will be able to write changes to it.

This is kinda similar to what you want to do: http://www.johnfindlay.plus.com/lcc-win32/asm/SelDelNT.htm

Instead of deleting it, obviously, you want to make changes. The idea behind the madness is the same - you must unmap the file.

Comment: @ddebug: I agree ,it's a fine question and this is fine answer (+1). There should be more open-minds like you.

Comment: @ddebug to complete the story, perhaps you can also explain how to write to a file when you don't have sufficient rights to do so

Comment: @David Heffernan, I don't think I understand what you're trying to get at. No where in mrwoik's statement did he say he didn't have write permission of his executable. He wanted to modify his image at runtime. Windows locks your file when it is in use as it is being executed. You can remove this lock by using UnmapViewOfFile. Though, this prevents further code execution of your executable, but the link I posted above shows a workaround for that. This might be too advanced for your David, but, if you do read the resource I linked you MIGHT understand it.

Comment: @ddebug the norm, since UAC and Vista, is that you don't have write access to executable files

Comment: @ddebug on the other hand, since the OP appears to be targetting single user systems, perhaps I shouldn't assume that this is a normal setup

Comment: @David Heffernan, I'm on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit right now. I can easily CreateFile, WriteFile, CloseHandle on any executable file I have on my hard drive. I can't do that if the file is running, however, I can do that if the file is not running in memory and is just sitting on the my drive. So, I would say that is an incorrect statement. UAC is enabled for me. If I start my file with "Administrator" privileges, I have no limit. If I don't start my file with "Administrator" privileges, I can still write to any executable/path that my current user has permission to access.

Comment: @ddebug As I said, the norm is that you don't have write access to executable files. And what's with the deal with denying the existence of multiple users on a system. Whatever this program is, I don't want to run it, not least because I can only imagine it's malware of some description!

Comment: @ddebug: "I can't do that if the file is running, however, I can do that if the file is not running in memory and is just sitting on the my drive." So, how are you claiming it's possible to write self-modifying code? Wouldn't this work *while* the application is running?

Comment: @Cody Gary, I was mentioning something not related to the link I posted above or to mrmoik's original request/statement. It's not really self modifying if I am using an external executable to use CreateFile/WriteFile/CloseHandle to "modify a generic executable" which is what I meant when I replied to David's statement.

Comment: @ddebug: Uh, what? I'm quoting *directly from your answer*, which is in response to a question about modifying the resource contents of a *running executable*. Even you indicate that such is not possible. There's no mention of an "external executable" in either the original question or your answer. In your apparent rush to avoid "giving irrelevant and horrible advice", you've done exactly that.

Comment: @Cody Gary, you took my statement out of context. It was meant as a reply to, David. I quote "since UAC and Vista, is that you don't have write access to executable files". It was to illustrate that a simple call to CreateFile/WriteFile/and CloseHandle proved that David Heffernan was incorrect in his statement. If you wanted to write to a process in use, you could still do so, it just wouldn't be as simple as CreateFile/WriteFile/CloseHandle...

Comment: @Cody Gary, You'd need to OpenProcess, suspend it, unmap the file, and then you could CreateFile/WriteFile/CloseHandle. Afterwards, if you wanted to resume the process with the changes, loop through the image's sections on disk, restore the unmapped executable (by remapping it), and resume the application.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unfortunately that SelDelNT doesn't work on XP+ - it can unmap the file, but
   exe image handle is not 0x4 anymore - in fact stdin handle is 0x3 and stdout handle is 0x7,
   so its likely that exe handle was intentionally made inaccessible (-1 or something).
2. One possibility is to rename the exe (its allowed), then copy it to the file
   with original name and modify it, and use MoveFileEx with MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT
   (or some other trick maybe) to delete it later.
3. A more obvious version of [2] is to copy the exe to %TEMP% first and restart from there.
4. VSS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384645(v=VS.85).aspx) may allow this 
   (via "restore") but its very slow and has noticeable side effects.
5. A /SWAPRUN:NET linker/editbin option seems to be relevant.
6. Here's a tutorial on updating resources in unlocked exe - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/Modify_UpdateResources_.aspx?msg=3307326
7. Here's another tutorial with a list of self-deleting methods: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/selfdel
   The last method (creating a suspended process with random exe like explorer or cmd.exe,
   then hijacking it) sounds like it would also work for exe modification - you can start
   cmd.exe in suspended state, then copy your exe image into memory of that process and release your original exe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the MSDN (UpdateResource Function) ? It has a list of things don't update your changes.
Maybe you are attempting one those.