# editing a text file in resource

Tags: c#, resources, text-files

I added a `text file` to a `resource` file in my c# project. In the application I see this file string like : ex.

```
    string fileContent = Properties.Resources.fileName;
```

My question is how can I edit the text file and save it back into the resource file using code?

Comment: And save it back in the resource you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be trying to un-bake an apple pie.

The program resources were NOT meant to be a writable database.  You should be loading and saving this information in the Environment.SpecialFolders.etc location.

If you "must" try this, an answer to this question might do what you want: [Modifying resource contents of a running executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577564/modifying-resource-contents-of-a-running-executable/4580404#4580404)

Comment: Another option for this kind of thing is to store info in Isolated Storage.  I suppose you could modify your application by writing two executables which could then modify each other, provided they weren't both running when you tried to edit one of them.  Still not really recommended though