# How to edit Text file in Resources Folder of Window form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

I am trying to Edit a text file which is consist in resources folder of window form project. C#.

I am using this code but it is not writing over text file. No errors come from this

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Namespace.Properties.Resources.textfile))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < res2.Count(); i++)
    {
        label3.Text = "Updating ... ";
        label3.Visible = true;
        label3.Refresh();

        file.WriteLine("asdasD");
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you debug it? Did you look in `Namespace.Properties.Resources.textfile` is this the correct Path of the file you want write into?

Comment: yes i did debug. i am able to read text from same path but not able to write.

Comment: Strange. Do you use this file in your project maybe in an other way, so it is used in the moment you want to write into? Did you try to write in this file with the same code, but in an other project while this project is closed?

Comment: yes i did read text with this method before writing.  string[] lines =SatakAntivirus.Properties.Resources.virus.ToString().Split('\n');

Comment: Where is your project folder located?

Comment: on desktop . Not in documents.

Answer (score 3):

As @LarsTech states in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122667/editing-a-text-file-in-resource), what you are trying to do is **not recommended**. Resource files are not meant to be written to--they should only be read from. If you want a place to put files, put them somewhere like `Environment.SpecialFolders`.

You could also use the `AppData` folder on the user's computer, which is typically used for exactly what you are trying to achieve:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "textfile.txt");    
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    //if the file doesn't exist, create it
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        File.Create(fileName);

    for (int i = 0; i < res2.Count(); i++)
    {
        label3.Text = "Updating ... ";
        label3.Visible = true;
        label3.Refresh();
        file.WriteLine("asdasD");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I removed the `file.Close()` since it isn't necessary if you are using the `using` block. You can do this if you are using a member which implements the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax125c9) interface, which `StreamWriter` does.

This should take care of everything for you. You won't have to create any files or worry about where they are.

Comment: You mean i should create new folder to put text data file their. So that user cannot read that file after installing my application in their system.

Comment: @AmritPal Yes, you can do that. Or you could use some predefined folders, like the `AppData` folder (which is what I would do). See updated answer.

Comment: I am doing the same as u said. But still user can see that files I want to not able to see this file.

Comment: I'm not sure how (if it's possible) to create a file that is completely inaccessible to the user. That might be a good topic for another StackOverflow question.

Comment: You could try messing around with file attributes, but even that won't COMPLETELY hide the file. See this article: http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

I am able to write and then read a file using your code in a console application. Can you run this code (console application) and tell me if you have any exception ?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "textfile.txt");
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            //if the file doesn't exist, create it
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                File.Create(fileName);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                file.WriteLine("asdas2");
            }
        }

        using(System.IO.StreamReader fr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

Note, if you are trying to append to the existing file (write at the end of it and keep existing content), you need to use System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true).